# Artifact deployed successfully but receive error 404 tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I´m trying to deploy a web application with Tomcat, log says artifact is deployed successfully but I still receive an 404 error. I´ve tried to follow some tutorials but haven´t found any way yet. Appreciate your help.

This is the log:

```
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener 
log INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server number:         7.0.75.0
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Version:            6.1
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Architecture:          amd64
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Edu\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_tutorial-database-service
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Edu\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_tutorial-database-service\conf\logging.properties
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\endorsed
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Edu\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_tutorial-database-service
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM o.a.c.s.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\temp
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: Cargada la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat 1.2.10 con la versión APR 1.5.2.
12-Feb 10:07:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros [false], aleatorio [true].
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL INFO: OpenSSL inicializado correctamente (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM o.a.c.s.Catalina load INFO: Initialization processed in 2017 ms
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Arrancando servicio Catalina
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
12-Feb 10:07:08 PM o.a.c.s.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 108 ms
[2017-02-12 10:07:09,074] Artifact OnFocusWeb: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
[2017-02-12 10:07:09,603] Artifact OnFocusWeb: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-02-12 10:07:09,603] Artifact OnFocusWeb: Deploy took 530 milliseconds
12-Feb 10:07:18 PM o.a.c.s.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
12-Feb 10:07:18 PM o.a.c.s.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\webapps\manager has finished in 172 ms
```

[artifacts config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhO7v.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Edited formatting a bit. Could you maybe give your web.xml or similar information ? It could be because it's deployed in a different context path than you're expecting.

Comment: It seems that you are missing the servlet mapping, can you add your web.xml or servlet mapping?

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?